# How to split MySQL entry into different lines using PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Using simple HTML textarea I added some records in MySQL. While adding the entries I pressed enter to separate the lines. Now I want to select/display those records using PHP in bullets. I want each lines to be displayed into bullets.

**E.g (the things I have added)**

```
Name

Age

Gender
```

**What I want**

- Name
- Age
- Gender

**I am using following PHP script**

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM students");
echo "<ul>";
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
  {
echo '<li'.$row["details"].'</li>';
  }
echo "</ul>";
```

Comment: Display them in a `<ul>`.

Comment: Use `explode()` to split the input at the newlines. Then loop over the lines, and display them as `<li>` elements.

Comment: Please show what you've tried so far so we can help you fix it.

Comment: I tried but it is retuning everything in single line.

Comment: where is your php code..

Comment: Can it be that when you're inserting the data into the DB, you're removing the breaks? (\n)

Comment: It is not possible now since there are already thousands of records in that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While i'm not sure it's a good practice (what if the users forgot to use a newline/enter?) you can use the `explode()` function.

[From the manual](http://php.net/explode):

> Returns an array of strings, each of which is a substring of string
>   formed by splitting it on boundaries formed by the string delimiter.

```
$listItems = explode("\n\n", $row['details']);
echo '<ul'>;
foreach($listItems as $item){
 echo '<li>'. $item .'</li>';
}
echo '</ul>';
```

**Please note**: You're using `mysql_` which is deprecated. Consider using `PDO`.

Comment: You're welcome, but still - it's not a good practice to rely on newlines. Consider using separated multiple inputs and serializing them as an array into the database.

Comment: Thanks for valuable suggestion. 
That database is around 5 years old and I am dealing with it.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
//assuming $result variable holds the db value from the textarea
$lines = explode("\n", $result);
echo "<ul>;
array_walk($lines, function($line) {
    $sanitizedLine = htmlentities($line);
    echo "<li>$sanitizedLine</li>";
});
echo "</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks for giving your valuable time.